# Proxy Setting Messed up while Using GitBash

Tags: git, github, proxy

I recently changed my Github username (due to some reasons) and after that when I used GitBash from Local then it shows Authentication failed. I saw a tutorial in which he changed some proxy settings in Gitbbash terminal, it was something like (I don't remember exactly)

```
git config --global http.proxy http://{domain}\\\{username}:{password}
```

Now When I try to fetch a remote repo in local it shows me error like

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/iamparasbansal/Learn_Gatsby.git/': Failed to connect to www.github.com port 8080: Timed out
```

Please help me resetting my proxy settings and setting it again properly.

Comment: fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/iamparasbansal/Learn_Gatsby.git/': Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8080: Connection refused

Comment: I made some changes in the proxy settings and now its showing this error